# Can it be that two S.M.A.R.T. hard drives die at the same time?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart, bad-sectors

I have a PC with 2 S.M.A.R.T. drives, of different makes and age. Both started complaining about bad sectors this week and finally failed.

The PC didn't fall or something.

Can it be that it's a matter of a failing SATA controller or a power source?

Comment: Grab some SMART software and test it to get a "second opinion"

Comment: Well, I did - Ubuntu does have a built-in SMART tool. I saw a lot of bad blocks on one that was still barely alive. The question is - why can be they failing at the same time? Was this a power leap or something?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this conclusively. For example, I have no way of knowing it wasn't elves with hammers (unless you don't believe in elves). It could be power, it could be bad luck, it could heat, it could be other types of radiation...

Comment: @Dave, look, I'm not asking what happened with my drives. What I'm asking is - does a factor exist that can cause two different drives to fail at the same time? Did anyone observe such? Can you assign a Bayesian probability to a universe with elves, to an universe with a power leap, with a failing power source, a failing SATA controller, a bad luck? If one has a probability greater than of a "bad luck", what is it?

Comment: He just told you: it could be power, various types of radiation, or anything else (including controller failure, IMO).

Comment: Look at it the other way around.  Say the odds are 1 in 1 million of two SMART drives randomly failing almost simultaneously.  But somewhere in the world will be that unlucky person it happens to.  What do they do?  They ask a question here about it because it is unexpected.  So it could be that you happen to be that person.

Answer (score 1):

I was right disbelieving in elves and anthropic principle.

It was an external factor: my BIOS was detecting both hard drives as "SMART bad", though only one of them was actually bad.

After disconnecting both and connecting a new good primary HDD, the secondary turned out to be good.